# How to speed up For loops in For loops in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm running the following in a batch file with an android device connected to pull some app data and its working however, I replete each code snip below for system apps and for 3rd party apps, and it's taking a long time due to what I think is the multiple FOR loops.

Can anyone recommend another way that would speed this up?

```
for /f "tokens=1 " %%a in ('adb.exe shell pm list users ^| grep.exe UserInfo ^| awk.exe -F "(UserInfo{)" "{print $2}" ^| awk.exe -F "(:)" "{print $1}"') do (
    echo User: %%a >> %FILENAME28%
    for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('adb.exe shell pm list packages -3 --user %%a ^| awk.exe -F "(package:)" "{print $2}"') do (
        for /f "tokens=*" %%c in ('adb.exe shell dumpsys package %%b ^| grep.exe -m1 versionName ^| awk.exe -F "(versionName=)" "{print $2}"') do set vversionName=%%c
        for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ('adb.exe shell dumpsys package %%b ^| grep.exe -m1 installerPackageName ^| awk.exe -F "(installerPackageName=)" "{print $2}"') do set vversionStore=%%d
        for /f "tokens=*" %%e in ('adb.exe shell pm dump %%b ^| grep.exe codePath ^| awk.exe -F "(codePath=)" "{print $2}"') do set CodePath=%%e
        echo App: %%b    Version: !vversionName!    Installed Via: !vversionStore!    Install Path: !CodePath! >> %FILENAME28%
    )
)
```

Comment: One simple thing you can do is move the redirection of output to 'filename28' to the outside of the nested loop by Wrapping the whole nest in Parenthesis and then redirecting the output of the entire code block

Comment: You are executing the same command `adb.exe shell dumpsys package %%b` twice (within `for /F %%c` and `for /F %%d`), which you could try to combine by adapting the following `grep` and `awk` commands. By the way: would the tag [tag:windows-subsystem-for-linux] apply to this question?

Comment: I did not apply windows-subsystem-for-linux tag as i'm using winGNU in CMD

Answer (score 1):

With regards to my comment:

```bat
(for /f "tokens=1 " %%a in ('adb.exe shell pm list users ^| grep.exe UserInfo ^| awk.exe -F "(UserInfo{)" "{print $2}" ^| awk.exe -F "(:)" "{print $1}"') do (
    echo User: %%a
    for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('adb.exe shell pm list packages -3 --user %%a ^| awk.exe -F "(package:)" "{print $2}"') do (
        for /f "tokens=*" %%c in ('adb.exe shell dumpsys package %%b ^| grep.exe -m1 versionName ^| awk.exe -F "(versionName=)" "{print $2}"') do set vversionName=%%c
        for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ('adb.exe shell dumpsys package %%b ^| grep.exe -m1 installerPackageName ^| awk.exe -F "(installerPackageName=)" "{print $2}"') do set vversionStore=%%d
        for /f "tokens=*" %%e in ('adb.exe shell pm dump %%b ^| grep.exe codePath ^| awk.exe -F "(codePath=)" "{print $2}"') do set CodePath=%%e
        echo App: %%b    Version: !vversionName!    Installed Via: !vversionStore!    Install Path: !CodePath!
    )
))>>"%FILENAME28%"
```

If filename28 is already doublequoted when defined, remove the doublequotes from the point of redirection.

Comment: That did not save any time in the commands tho


```Move >> outside of the FOR Loop
Start    Wed 06/03/2020 17:51:37.11
End     Wed 06/03/2020 18:01:23.17```

```after only scanning user 0
Start    Wed 06/03/2020 11:21:05.56
End      Wed 06/03/2020 11:31:31.92 ```

Comment: I can change the two grep -m1 commands into one however, I now have two results which I need to have in two variables which I have not figured out how to do yet.

```adb.exe shell dumpsys package %%b | grep.exe -E "installerPackageName|versionName" | awk.exe -F "(=)" "{print $2}"```